# Access node's properties/children from inline template

Tags: mps

I have a `template switch` where, based on the node's concept, I want to create runtime objects using that node's properties and/or children. The right-hand side of each case is an inline template. How do I access node's properties/children from that inline template? More specifically, in the screenshot below, the arguments to the `line()` and `rectangle()` methods need to be extracted from the corresponding `LineCommand` and `Rectangle` nodes.

Note that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> menu doesn't offer to "Add a Property Macro".

I am using MPS 2018.1.5.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to extract an argument from the node's children you need to add the template argument (e.g. "`null`") and then put the macro on it. Then in the process of generation, the template argument (`null`) will be replaced with the generation target of the node's children.
If you want to use the node's property, then you should add a more specific argument (e.g. empty string) and put the caret to the property cell (between the quotes) and then you will see the "Add Property Macro" intention

#### template argument

[image: template argument]

#### template argument with the property

[image: template argument with the property]

#### add property macro

[image: add property macro]

Answer (score 3):

Add a dummy argument first and then use Alt+Enter on the argument to add a macro to replace it with something from the node.